# Updating validity on FormArray property after validity change

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation, angular4-forms

I am using angular 4 to create a custom validator in a reactive form on a `FormArray` item that is an array. It works on the initial load, however if i add an item to the array and then remove that item, the `Validator.required` validation is than not set.

FromArray -> FormGroup

```
let customItemsValidator: Array<any> = item.selectType === 'custom' && item.required ? 
                                       [Validators.required] : [];

return this.formBuilder.group({
   customItems: [[], customItemsValidator],
})
```

main form on the main component.ts

```
this.appForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   option: this.formBuilder.array([]),
   items: this.formBuilder.array([])
});
```

So i can build the form and it works 100%, i have a submit button that is disabled if the form is not valid and on the initial load the button stays disabled until i add an item to the `customItems` property. Once i remove the added item the submit button is still enabled even though now it should be disabled because it is required and has no value.

the remove method

```
selectOptionsCustomRemove(customItem, customIdx: number, idx: number) {
  pullAt(this.items.at(idx).get('customItems').value, customIdx);
}
```

So it removes the item but the validity does not change on the form.

I have tried with the `updateValueAndValidity()` after the `pullAt` but this does not work seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out when i removed the item from the array it just left an empty `[]` because the `pullAt` just removed from the index, which left the property with a value of `[]`. So i had to assign the array to `null` so that the validation would trigger.

```
if (this.options.at(idx).get('customItems').value.length === 0) { 
        this.options.at(idx).patchValue({ customItems: null }) 
}
```